# Things that imply BQP Derandomization

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing

I am aware that it is generally believed that P = BPP, but BQP != P (since factoring is in BQP, and factoring seems hard.)

For BPP, we have the hardness vs randomness result: which states that circuit lower bounds for EXP imply derandomization results for BPP.

Even though I do not expect BQP to be simulatable in sub-exponential time, I am curious if there are any implication results along the lines of "If pigs can whistle, than donkeys can fly."

Formally, I'm asking if there exists provable statements of the form:

If [XYZ] then BQP can be simulated in sub-exponential time.

Ideally, [XYZ] would be about the hardness of certain problems against certain complexity classes. However, any XYZ not of the form "BQP can be simulated in sub-exponential time" would be interesting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting!  I don't know of any *nontrivial* result of that kind -- neither one that says "if [XYZ] then BPP=BQP", nor one that says "if [XYZ] then BQP ⊆ BPTIME(2<sup>o(n)</sup>)."  The closest I can think of is a result of [Terhal and DiVincenzo](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205133), who showed that if constant-depth quantum sampling can be efficiently classically simulated then BQP ⊆ AM.  (Later work, by Bremner-Jozsa-Shepherd and myself and Arkhipov, shows that the same assumption would even imply P<sup>#P</sup> = BPP<sup>NP</sup>.)  Combining that with some assumption that gave AM ⊆ BPTIME(2<sup>o(n)</sup>) would then yield what you wanted.

Comment: So is the best we have: "if quantumness can be simulated, then ...". Thus, do we not have a statement of the form: "If (EXP is not contained in subexp quantum w/ subexp quantum advice) then BQP is in subexp time" ?

Comment: Well, EXP *can't* be contained in deterministic subexponential time, because of the Time Hierarchy Theorem.  EXP *could* be contained in BPSUBEXP.  And if so, then it would indeed follow that BQP was in BPSUBEXP, but merely because BQP is contained in EXP!  So I didn't count that as a "nontrivial" example of the sort of result you were looking for.

Comment: I think I'm asking something different. Hardness vs Randomness states: if EXP does not have sub-exp size circuits, then BPP can be simulated in polynomial time. I'm interested if there's a statement of the form: if EXP does not have sub-exp size _quantum_ circuits, then BQP can be simulated in subexp time.

Comment: Ah, sorry!  No, I don't know of any result of that form (and would consider it quite unlikely, as someone who believes both that EXP doesn't have subexp-size quantum circuits and that BQP can't be simulated in subexp time...)

Comment: All is clear now. Thanks! (My intuition agrees with your intuition, but I wanted to double check as complexity has destroyed faith in things I can't prove.)